# How to add custom Accept-Languages to Chrome for pseudolocalization testing?

Tags: google-chrome, localization, internationalization, http-accept-language, pseudolocalization

i am testing [pseudo-localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042920/how-to-use-enable-pseudo-locale-in-windows-for-testing) of a web-site.

i can configure Internet Explorer to have custom accept languages:

1. Click **Tools**, **Internet Options**
2. On the **General** tab click **Languages**
3. In the **Language Preferences** dialog click **Add**.
4. Enter a user-defined language of `qps-ploc` (i.e. the Pseudo (Base) locale)
5. Click **OK**

[image]

Now when Internet Explorer issues an http request, the accept languages will lead with `qpc-ploc`:

```
GET https://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Accept-Language: qps-ploc,en-US;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

How do i perform the same change to Chrome? To Firefox?

---

**Update**

It should also be noted that Internet Explorer *honors* my Windows preferences. My Windows is configured to use **Pseudo (Base)** `qps-ploc` locale. By default Internet Explorer uses it.

Google Chrome *ignores* my Windows preferences, deciding instead to request `en-US` and `en` language:

```
GET https://stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.220 Safari/535.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Comment: What's the point of testing it in different browsers?

Comment: @EduardoMolteni: Not everyone uses Internet Explorer as their default browser. If a developer hits `F5` in Visual Studio it might open Chrome or FireFox.

Comment: Fair enough. Check out the updated answer with Chrome.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### In Firefox

Use `about:config`

[image]

[image]

(There is a typo in qps-ploc in the screenshots, but you surely get the idea)

### In Chrome

(***Edit**: refer to the comments for ways to avoid Chrome override the setting in new versions.*)

Edit the file `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`, and add:

```
{ ...

   "intl": {
      "accept_languages": "qps-ploc,en-us,en"
   },

   ...
}
```

For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. Colleague here today needed to enable it in Chrome. And while it's a pain enough that he'll use IE instead - the answer is still complete.

Comment: Note that Chrome should be shut down when you edit the file. It can get overwritten if you don't

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m on Windows 7. I closed Chrome, added "vo" as language, saved, re-opened the file to check to see whether the update was saved, ok. Started Chrome and the setting was removed from the file.

Comment: After restart Chrome tries to fix the config and removes your Chrome user profile. Chrome 25 , Win 7 64bit

Comment: I have the same issue with Windows 7 64bit. Is it possible to prevent Chrome from replacing my values of accept_languages?

Comment: I needed to sign out from Chrome in order to have ability to change accept_languages from file. (Chrome stores its configuration in sqlite3 local db and I think it loads the same database from Google servers and then compare them (or smth like this))

Comment: We use "vo" to show resourcekeys and "ie" to show developer resources.

Changing accept_languages (and I guess all settings) doesn't work when you're logged into Chrome and sync your SETTINGS. You can disable Chrome Settings > Advanced sync setting > Choose specific items to sync and uncheck Settings.

Then close all chrome.exe processes via Windows Task Manger (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), edit the file Preferences, and add an accept_language up front. Save the file Preferences and start Google Chrome.

There is also a --lang= parameter but that somehow doesn't seem to work for this purpose.

Comment: I cannot get this fix to work.  I've killed all my Chrome.exe processes in task manager. I've edited Preferences and added zh-XX to accept_languages at the beginning (and end during other tests). Chrome does not overwrite the change.  I'm running Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m (64-bit).

Comment: Regarding the Firefox solution, how can I modify the `relative quality factor q`?

Answer (score 41):

You can also set this via the settings page.

Go to settings (cmd + , on mac, probably cntrl + , on windows) and search for language. Click the "manage languages" link and add your preferred language. After that just drag your language to the top of the list and you're done!

[image: The search results and the manage languages link]

Or direct access to languages settings: chrome://settings/languages

[image: The languages list]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for all languages available in Windows. Chrome only lets you add languages that it, internally, recognizes. But it's a good stop-gap for the more common languages.

Comment: it seems that display language and accept language are two different things

Comment: @serhio: Except that it is. Somehow (thanks to the translate bar?), Chrome decided I'd rather read overly-sensitive Web 3.0 pages in German (a language I'm far from fluent in) instead of English. This answer was just the thing I needed to reset my `Accept-Language` header from `en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.4` to `en-US,en;q=0.8`.

Comment: или сразу: chrome://settings/languages

Answer (score 1):

"intl.accept_languages" did not work on the latest version of Chrome, after go through the code of Advanced Page Language Switcher (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-page-language-sw/mhgjlbolkmcookadjpolimbddngjgbol). You can change it using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener`.

Some sample code was like the following (copied from the above extension's backgroud.js).

```js
var locale = "",
    ulrLocation = "",
  contentLang = "";

let extraInfoSpec = ["blocking", "requestHeaders"];
if (chrome.webRequest.OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions.hasOwnProperty('EXTRA_HEADERS')) {
  extraInfoSpec.push('extraHeaders');
} 
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(HEADERS_INFO){
  for (var header of HEADERS_INFO.requestHeaders) {
    if (header.name == "Accept-Language") {
        header.value = locale;
    }
  }

  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {language: locale});
  });

  return {  requestHeaders: HEADERS_INFO.requestHeaders };
},{ urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, extraInfoSpec );

var setLocale = function(x) {
  locale = x;
}
var setCasinoLocation = function(y, z) {
  ulrLocation = y;
  contentLang = z;
}
//Listen for redirect requests
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
  return;
});
```