# Start Google Chrome with a specific locale (using a command line argument)

Tags: google-chrome

How can I start Google Chrome with a specific locale using command line arguments?

According to *[List of Chromium command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)*,

```
chrome.exe --lang DE
```

should work. However, it does not.

Comment: These command lines switches are for Chromium some of them, like --lang may not work on Google Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add custom Accept-Languages to Chrome for pseudolocalization testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769061/how-to-add-custom-accept-languages-to-chrome-for-pseudolocalization-testing)

Comment: check my answer if my important info maybe was your problem

Answer (score 21):

Other suggestions do not work in [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)) (Jessie). This works for me:

```
LANGUAGE=de google-chrome
```

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, does't seems to work because after the chrome is launched, I open the console and write `navigator.language` which outputs another lg

Answer (score 12):

`path_to_chrome.exe --lang=locale` (notice the `=` sign)

Comprehensive instricution on how to set your browser's locale: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#locales-testing

List of supported locales:
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n#localeTable

Comment: Have you tried that? Browser is still English, and `Accept-Language` is still `en-US;en`

Comment: @D.R. `chrome.exe --lang=de` works just fine on windows 8, just tested. `DE` vs `de` issue?

Comment: I've tried `de` now, still does not work. It is only changing the UI language - I'm on Win 8.1 and Chrome 36.x. Are you sure the Accept-Language has changed?

Comment: @D.R. You are right, interface language is german and google login-to-browser page is also german, but `Accept-Language` is still the default one: https://imgur.com/5Y3GI8m . If you believe this is a bug, please report it: http://crbug.com.

Comment: @D.R. Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769061/how-to-add-custom-accept-languages-to-chrome-for-pseudolocalization-testing) or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/478565/chrome-extension-for-switching-locale-accept-languages) ?

Answer (score 9):

In my case anyway, I had to specify both `en-US` and `en` to get everything set up correctly.

This was my command-line argument:

```
--lang=en-US,en
```

You might also try:

```
--lang=en_US
```

Comment: maybe because your first locale `en-US` is not working and you should try it with `--lang=en_US`. In the docs they also use a an underscore.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, it's just working with

```
chrome.exe --lang=en_US
```

**Important:** You need to close all other Chrome windows! Otherwise, the locale of the current opened chrome process will be taken.

**Alternative:** Is to choose a different user-data-dir. With `--user-data-dir=tmp` you can keep your chrome open.

Answer (score 4):

For the latest Chrome versions, the below command should work.

```
path_to_chrome.exe --accept-lang=en-GB
```

Need to follow protocol language[-country]. Refer https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#accept-lang

It can even give multiple languages using comma as the delimiter.

```
path_to_chrome.exe --accept-lang=en-GB,en-US
```

Note: If you have Chrome already open, it'll open new window in the same session and hence changes you might not see locales reflecting. Either close existing sessions, else use  `--user-data-dir=/path` ([refer](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#user-data-dir)) to start an isolated session.

Comment: Great, it changes `navigator.language` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a solution to define the language for Chrome without even starting it or update the EXE file shortcut.

It is possible to force a language and a locale for Chrome with the registry on Windows.

You need two keys to be changed ***with administrator rights***:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"ApplicationLocaleValue"="fr"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome\ForcedLanguages]
"1"="fr-FR"
```

This is forcing the language so **all users will not be able to update it with the Chrome UI**.

If you need to force a language and be able to modify it with the UI, maybe there is a solution on the official documentation linked below.

Official documentation:

- [ApplicationLocaleValue](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ApplicationLocaleValue)
- [ForcedLanguages](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ForcedLanguages)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Chrome with the headless option, then use the below:

```
options.addArguments("--accept-lang=de-DE");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your attempt to contribute, but this doesn't answer the question that was asked, which was how to do it from the command-line.  [This question](/q/69980736) (and possible others) covers how to do it with headless Chrome in Selenium, and there's already an answer there with the same information you posted.  We *try* to keep each question focused on a single topic whenever possible so that answers can be targeted specifically to answer the question that was asked.  Thanks!