# How do I use the --lang switch with chrome.exe to create a Chrome instance with English-UK?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a script that at some point needs to open a Chrome Browser with a different language setting than the default, specifically English-UK.  Following the documentation found at http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html I use the line

```
.\chrome.exe --lang-en-UK
```

This still opens a Browser with the default English-US settings that I have.  What is the proper syntax for using the --lang flag?

Comment: usually you use a space or an equals between the option and the parameter.

Comment: yeah the equals helped set it correctly.  The issue for me was that I also needed to set the browser locale\accept-language

Comment: found my solution following the links posted on this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992240/start-google-chrome-with-a-specific-locale-using-a-command-line-argument)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the parameter --lang="en-US" or "en-UK" with "" (quotation marks)