# ASP.NET MVC CurrentCulture, from user or server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, currentculture

Quick question that I couldn't find a clear answer on, if I get the CurrentCulture of a thread in an MVC application, is this the culture based on the user's browser/OS, or the culture that is set on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enabled `enableClientBasedCulture` in your `Web.Config`:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
</system.web>
```

Then client culture will be used, otherwise it will use the server culture.

You can also set a fallback culture in case the client didn't send the `AcceptLanguage` header, by setting the `culture` and `uiCulture` properties as well:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection.enableclientbasedculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Weird thing is though, is that when I run my app, even from different browsers (that are set to language = NL, I'm not in the US), it will always give me EN-US as current culture. Even if I get the language from the httpcontext-request userlanguages.

Comment: Can you check the actual `Accept-Language` header value that you're sending?

Comment: Regardless of the browser, I get: "en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6"

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769061/how-to-add-custom-accept-languages-to-chrome-for-pseudolocalization-testing on how to change your first language to `nl`