# HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE always showing english

Tags: php, http-accept-language

I'm trying to get the current user's language settings using:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
```

When I VPN into another country, or even use geopeeker.com, I still get "en" when I echo out $lang.

Is this method not the best way of going about this? Or is my method of testing flawed?

Answer (score 1):

The Accept-Language header is not set by the country you're visiting from, it's set by **your browser**. If *you*, with the same browser, VPN to another country, your browser will still send the same header. It's either a setting in your browser's preferences, or the browser takes it from the system's locale preferences.

Comment: Why is it then, if I go to another site like PayPal via my VPN, it will detect Spanish as my language, for example?

Comment: 'Cause they ignore the Accept-Language header and use your IP to geolocate you and infer your language…?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your browser settings and is sent up in the request headers. See [How to add custom Accept-Languages to Chrome for pseudolocalization testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769061/how-to-add-custom-accept-languages-to-chrome-for-pseudolocalization-testing) for changing your browser settings, or consider using something like curl to manually specify them.