# How to enable Pseudo-language on Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows, localization, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pseudolocalization

I can't seem to enable Pseudo-language on the WP8 emulator. Most tutorials suggest to set the localization via the development operating system, and that these settings somehow "trickle down" into the emulator, but this doesn't seem to work for me -- the emulator just defaults to English no matter how I have my OS language/keyboard set (Control Panel -> Language -> Move Up <language> to top -> restart emulator).

I can change localization settings within the phone's "Settings", and although other languages successfully translate within my app, Pseudo is not an option.

I have Googled lots of MSDN information (including [documentation on how to troubleshoot this  specific issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj649135.aspx)) and I have seemingly exhausted my options.

tl;dr Has anyone had trouble with the "trickle down" of localization settings into the Windows Phone emulator? How do you fix it?

Comment: Maybe the better question is has anyone gotten "trickle down" to work on the Windows Phone 8 emulator using Windows 8/Visual Studio 2012 Update 3?

Comment: I've never heard of the concept of the Windows culture settings "trickling down" to WP8 emulator. I know that it works for Windows Store (aka. "Metro") apps. Are you sure? Can you perhaps post a link relevant to WP8 emulator?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042920/how-to-use-enable-pseudo-locale-in-windows-for-testing

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution recommended by Microsoft

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("qps-ploc");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("qps-ploc");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj569303.aspx

Comment: To enable pseudo, add the following code to the App.xaml.cs file in the InitializeLanguage() method, just after the try statement:

Answer (score 0):

When I want to run my WP8 app in pseudo-loc, I add the following line to the beginning of App constructor:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("qps-ploc");
```