# Issues with using UTF-8 with PHPMailer

Tags: utf-8, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer 5 to send plain text emails from forms.  It looks like some users are pasting content from word into the textarea fields and the resulting email comes out with lots of non-readable characters (e.g. â€œ).

I've tried adding $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; and that seems to fix the tests I've done (e.g. bullet lists are now coming through properly).

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
```

Are there any security issues or other issues that could come up from setting the character set to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right. PHPMailer defaults (as does PHP's internal `mail` function) to the ISO-8859-1 character set because that can be used in the absence of the `mbstring` PHP extension which is not available by default - and if you don't have that extension, UTF-8 support won't work. Once you switch to using UTF-8, your entire toolchain must also use UTF-8 - your editors, your database, your database connection. You also need to be wary of functions like `strlen` and `substr`, which are not UTF-8-safe because they work in bytes, not chars (which may be more than 1 byte long). Whenever one of those things gets it wrong, you'll see the kind of corruption you have. It's a good exercise to stick in some difficult strings to test with (though see [my answer about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16203718/333340)) to make sure it comes through unscathed.

Unfortunately, MS Word is one of the best examples of how to do UTF-8 badly; it often riddles the text with unnecessary unusual characters, extra control chars etc, so I would advise doing some heavy filtering on your inputs - editors like CKEditor have built-in filters to help deal with Word's issues. That doesn't have anything to do with PHPMailer, it's a just a common problem with dealing with input that has been touched by Word.

The only thing you're doing wrong is using PHPMailer 5.x; current version is 6.x.

Comment: Thanks.  We plan to upgrade to v6 but need to upgrade PHP first.  I'm not using a database, just sending to an email so that won't be a problem.  We have a plain textarea box, no wysiwyg, but it looks like people are copying lists into it from Word.  Thanks for the details on potential issues.  I don't know a whole lot about character set differences.